# Translation of Semantic Predicate from Antr3 to Antr4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

In my Antlr3 grammar, I used the following lexer rule to recognizer a constant date period such as "1 YEAR 4 MONTHS":

```
(DATE_PERIOD_CONSTANT)=> DATE_PERIOD_CONSTANT ((' '+ DATE_PERIOD_CONSTANT)=> ' '+ DATE_PERIOD_CONSTANT)*
```

(Credit where credit is due, that came from Bart Kiers).

Unfortunately, that syntax has gone away in ANTLR4. So, I've unsuccessfully tried the following:

```
DATE_PERIOD_CONSTANT
: (INTEGER ' '+ (YEAR | MONTH | WEEK | DAY))+
| {getText().matches("(\\d+ (YEAR(S)?|MONTH(S)?|WEEK(S)?|DAY(S)?))+")}? INTEGER
;

INTEGER
    : DIGIT+
    ;

 fragment DIGIT:'0'..'9';

// YEAR/MONTH/WEEK/DAY definition
```

That was unsuccessful as well.

Can anyone help me translate to the new format?

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example lexer rule uses *syntactic* predicates, not semantic predicates. These are unecessary in ANTLR 4 due to its greatly improved lookahead ability. All you have to do is remove them:

```
DATE_PERIOD_CONSTANT (' '+ DATE_PERIOD_CONSTANT)*
```